# How can I convert spline in Matlab to python?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I used `interp1` in **matlab** with the method '`spline`', is there a function in any python packages can stead of it?

I have tried `interp1d` in scipy with the `kind='cubic'`, but it has different results with  `interp1` in **matlab** with the method '`spline`', although not very big.

And I have found people saying that `InterplotationUnivariateSpline` with `k=3` is same as interp1d with `kind='cubic'`, is it true? And what about `CubicSpline`?In docs they say that the resulting spline will be the same as returned by `splrep` (with s=0) and `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`, but they also say that it doesn't use B-spline basis like `splrep` (with s=0) and `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`.

**Matlab code:**

```
ppx = interp1(samplez,samplex,'spline','pp');
interpx = ppval(ppx,interpz);
```

**python code:**

```
from scipy import interpolate
interplinex = interpolate.interp1d(samplez, samplex, kind='cubic')
interpx = interplinex(interpz)
```

The result named `interpx` in **Matlab** is different with the result named `interpx` in **python**

Comment: Welcome! Consider editing your post to use syntax highlighting for the example code.

Comment: What do you mean by "different results"? Could you provide the data you are using and all the code?